# Spliterator Stream passing results to the next tream consumer

Tags: java, java-stream, spliterator

Given the following code

```java
public class StreamSpliteratorTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var ids = Stream.generate(() -> RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(5))
            .limit(100)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        get(ids)
            .forEach(resultMap -> {
                System.out.printf("Got result map with size %s%n", resultMap.size());
            });
    }

    static Stream<Map<String, String>> get(Collection<String> ids) {
        var remainginIds = new HashSet<>(ids);
        var initialCount = remainginIds.size();
        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(new Iterator<>() {

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return !remainginIds.isEmpty();
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> next() {
                Map<String, String> result = Map.of();

                try {
                    var chunk = remainginIds.stream().limit(10).collect(Collectors.toSet());
                    remainginIds.removeAll(chunk);
                    result = fetch(chunk).get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    System.out.printf("%s of %s ids done%n", initialCount - remainginIds.size(), initialCount);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.printf("Request thread pool was interrupted: %s%n", e.getMessage());
                }

                return result;
            }
        }, Spliterator.IMMUTABLE), true);
    }

    static CompletableFuture<Map<String, String>> fetch(Collection<String> ids) {
        var delay = CompletableFuture.delayedExecutor(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> ids.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e, e -> e)), delay);
    }
}
```

The result of which is

```
10 of 100 ids done
20 of 100 ids done
30 of 100 ids done
40 of 100 ids done
50 of 100 ids done
60 of 100 ids done
70 of 100 ids done
80 of 100 ids done
90 of 100 ids done
100 of 100 ids done
Got result map with size 10
Got result map with size 10
Got result map with size 10
Got result map with size 10
Got result map with size 10
Got result map with size 10
Got result map with size 10
Got result map with size 10
Got result map with size 10
Got result map with size 10
```

I am confused as to why the result of one execution of `next()` isn't immediately passed on to the next consumer in the calling code? I would expect this to result in this output:

```
10 of 100 ids done
Got result map with size 10
20 of 100 ids done
Got result map with size 10
30 of 100 ids done
Got result map with size 10
40 of 100 ids done
Got result map with size 10
50 of 100 ids done
Got result map with size 10
60 of 100 ids done
Got result map with size 10
70 of 100 ids done
Got result map with size 10
80 of 100 ids done
Got result map with size 10
90 of 100 ids done
Got result map with size 10
100 of 100 ids done
Got result map with size 10
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Spliterator` returned from `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize` tries to batch a number of elements from the iterator in order to increase parallel performance.

You can see this here: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/51b53a821bb3cfb962f80a637f5fb8cde988975a/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Spliterators.java#L1828

To avoid this you could use a different spliterator or switch the stream to sequential mode by calling the `sequential()` method before `forEach(...)`.

One way to keep using a parallel stream would be to move your batching out to before the stream and use the `Arrays.stream` method:

```
static Stream<Map<String, String>> get(Collection<String> ids) {
    List<String>[] chunks = new List[ids.size() / 10 + 1];
    Arrays.setAll(chunks, i -> new ArrayList<>());
    int i = 0;
    for(String id : ids){
        chunks[i++ / 10].add(id);
    }
    AtomicInteger done = new AtomicInteger(0);
    int initialCount = ids.size();
    return Arrays.stream(chunks).map(c -> {
        Map<String, String> result = Map.of();
        try {
            result = fetch(c).get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.printf("%s of %s ids done%n", done.addAndGet(c.size()), initialCount);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.printf("Request thread pool was interrupted: %s%n", e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }).parallel();
}
```

Comment: After reading this, I tired to simply switch the `parallel` argument of the Spliterator to `false` and now it works as expected. However of course, I lose the ability to fully utilize multithreading now ... hmm

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think what is happening is that the method `StreamSupport.stream()` actually traverses the Iterator first in order to create the Stream, that later on you use forEach.

```
StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(new Iterator<>() {
```

The forEach method is not physically called for each (Next), but rather on the (Stream) which was populated from the Iterator previously.  That is why you see the sequence you see.